# jquery hover add 2 classes to 2 different div's

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass

What I have is as follow:

(I have  "holder" div 2,3 or more times on same page )

```
<div class="holder">

    <div class="one">one something </div>
    <div class="two">two something</div>
    <ul class="ulclass">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    <ul>
</div>

<div class="holder">

    <div class="one">one something </div>
    <div class="two">two something</div>
    <ul class="ulclass">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

....

then I have some jQuery that goes like this:

```
$(".holder").hover(function()
{

$(this).addClass("addedClass");

}, function () {

$(this).removeClass("addedClass");

});
```

This add class to .holder when I hover it.
What I need is to when hover over .holder to add another class 'liaddclas' to li element

```
<div class="holder addedClass">
    <div class="one">one something </div>
    <div class="two">two something</div>
    <ul class="ulclass">
        <li class="liaddclas"></li>
    <ul>
</div>

I tried with 
$(".holder").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("addedClass");
        $(this "li").addClass("liaddclas");
        }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("addedClass");
        $(this "li").removeClass("liaddclas"); 
    });
```

but this add class liaddclass to all .holder dives I have on page when I hover on .holder and I want to add it to just one div at the time...
THx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Here is one:

```
$(this).find('li').addClass("liaddclas");
```

Answer (score 0):

To select just the li elements within the currently hovered div you can do this:

```
$(".holder").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("addedClass");
    $("li",this).addClass("liaddclas");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("addedClass");
    $("li",this).removeClass("liaddclas"); 
});
```

This is just one of many ways to do it, but the syntax `$("li",this)` selects all li elements within the context of `this`.

The syntax you had, `$(this "li")` is simply invalid JavaScript.